# Standard Imperial and Standard Metric for rotary switches

Tags: switches, rotary

I have been researching about rotary switches, I was confused when I read in a datasheet that has standard imperial and standard metric. Can anybody please explain to me what is the difference between standard imperial and standard metric rotary switches?

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lorlin/CK1033?qs=Jslch3jnSjm61SjQtBRQZg%3D%3D

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It says in the top table what the mechanical differences are.

Comment: 6.35 mm = 1/4 inch. A standard shaft diameter in the Imperial system.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" means that the values are the ones listed in the table. A non-standard part number would be one for e.g. a metric dimensioned switch with an 80mm spindle, for example.

Comment: Thanks for this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The mounting hardware is different.  One uses imperial sized mountings, and the other is metric.

Comment: Thanks for your comment good sir. appreciate it.